# Why Postgres does not use GIN index if I specify a LIMIT clause?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-performance, postgresql-14

I have a table containing about 5 million records and a GIN index on `Barcodes` column.

I have this query:

```
SELECT T1.*
  FROM public."Skus" AS T1
 WHERE (T1."Barcodes" && '{ "THE_BARCODE" }')
 LIMIT 11;
```

It takes very long (seconds) and the explain shows me the db is constantly running a `seq scan`.

Now, if I omit the `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT T1.*
  FROM public."Skus" AS T1
 WHERE (T1."Barcodes" && '{ "THE_BARCODE" }');
```

it takes only a few milliseconds and the explain shows me an `index scan`.

Why? How to avoid/overcome this?

**Note**: *queries are dynamically generated by application, so isn't easy to remove the `LIMIT' (and sometimes it is even necessary).*

Additional information as specified at: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

### Postgres version

`SELECT version();`

gives

`PostgreSQL 14.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit`

### Operating system+version

Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server

### Full Table and Index Schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."Skus"
(
    "Id" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "Style" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "ColorId" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "DropId" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "SizeId" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "LotId" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Barcodes" text[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "AuthorizationTags" text[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "CreatedBy" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "CreatedOn" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "UpdatedBy" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "UpdatedOn" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_Skus" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."Skus"
    OWNER to azadmin;
-- Index: IX_Skus_Barcodes

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public."IX_Skus_Barcodes";

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "IX_Skus_Barcodes"
    ON public."Skus" USING gin
    ("Barcodes" COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    WITH (fastupdate=True)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

### Table Metadata

About 5 milions rows

```
SELECT relname, relpages, reltuples, relallvisible, relkind, relnatts, relhassubclass, reloptions, pg_table_size(oid)
  FROM pg_class
 WHERE relname='TABLE_NAME'
```

gives:

- relname          Skus
- relpages         198436
- reltuples        5,13E+12
- relallvisible    198312
- relkind          r
- relnatts         12
- relhassubclass   FALSE
- reloptions
- pg_table_size    1626071040

*Does the table have anything unusual about it?*

- contains large objects: **NO**
- has a large proportion of NULLs in several columns: **NO**
- receives a lot of UPDATEs or DELETEs regularly: **NO**
- is growing rapidly: **NO**
- has many indexes on it: **NO**
- uses triggers that may be executing database functions, or is calling functions directly: **NO**

### EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS), not just EXPLAIN

Note: `SET track_io_timing = on` is prohibited by Azure

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) SELECT T1.*
  FROM public."Skus" AS T1
 WHERE (T1."Barcodes" && '{ "7622336162738" }')
 LIMIT 11;
```

gives this: https://explain.depesz.com/s/xZj7

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) SELECT T1.*
  FROM public."Skus" AS T1
 WHERE (T1."Barcodes" && '{ "7622336162738" }');
```

gives this: https://explain.depesz.com/s/vrFZ

### History

The query with LIMIT has always been slow, the other one has always been fast

### Hardware

Azure instance type: Burstable, B2s, 2 vCores, 4 GiB RAM, 32 GiB storage

### Hardware benchmark

N/A (Azure)

### Maintenance Setup

- Are you running autovacuum? **I don't know**
- If so, with what settings?
- If not, are you doing manual VACUUM and/or ANALYZE? **NO**
- How often?

  SELECT *
  FROM pg_stat_user_tables
  WHERE relname='table_name

gives:

- relid                    33377
- schemaname               public
- relname                  Skus
- seq_scan                 24
- seq_tup_read             96704575
- idx_scan                 30
- idx_tup_fetch            5126593
- n_tup_ins                5129364
- n_tup_upd                0
- n_tup_del                0
- n_tup_hot_upd            0
- n_live_tup               5127368
- n_dead_tup               2580
- n_mod_since_analyze      0
- n_ins_since_vacuum       0
- last_vacuum              2023-08-01 22:58:49.72915+00
- last_autovacuum          2023-08-01 22:03:13.66993+00
- last_analyze             2023-08-01 22:58:56.888834+00
- last_autoanalyze         2023-08-01 22:03:19.781057+00
- vacuum_count             1
- autovacuum_count         7
- analyze_count            1
- autoanalyze_count        8

### WAL Configuration

For data writing queries: have you moved the WAL to a different disk? Changed the settings? Not a writing query

### GUC Settings

```
SELECT name, current_setting(name), source
  FROM pg_settings
 WHERE source NOT IN ('default', 'override');
```

gives:

- name                                 current_setting source
- archive_command                      BlobLogUpload.sh %f %p  configuration file
- archive_mode                         always  configuration file
- archive_timeout                      5min    configuration file
- authentication_timeout               30s configuration file
- azure.extensions                     HSTORE,POSTGRES_FDW configuration file
- backend_flush_after                  2MB configuration file
- bgwriter_delay                       20ms    configuration file
- bytea_output                         hex session
- checkpoint_completion_target         0.9 configuration file
- checkpoint_timeout                   10min   configuration file
- client_encoding                      UTF8    session
- client_min_messages                  notice  session
- cron.                                enable_superuser_jobs   off configuration file
- cron.                                host    /tmp    configuration file
- DateStyle                            ISO, MDY    session
- default_text_search_config           pg_catalog.english  configuration file
- dynamic_shared_memory_type           posix   configuration file
- effective_cache_size                 3GB configuration file
- hot_standby                          on  configuration file
- jit                                  off configuration file
- lc_messages                          en_US.utf8  configuration file
- lc_monetary                          en_US.utf-8 configuration file
- lc_numeric                           en_US.utf-8 configuration file
- lc_time                              en_US.utf8  configuration file
- listen_addresses                     *   configuration file
- log_checkpoints                      on  configuration file
- log_connections                      on  configuration file
- log_disconnections                   on  configuration file
- log_line_prefix                      %t-%c-  configuration file
- log_replication_commands             on  configuration file
- log_rotation_age                     1h  configuration file
- log_rotation_size                    100MB   configuration file
- log_timezone                         UTC configuration file
- logging_collector                    off configuration file
- maintenance_work_mem                 154MB   configuration file
- max_connections                      50  configuration file
- max_parallel_maintenance_workers     64  configuration file
- max_stack_depth                      2MB environment variable
- max_wal_size                         2GB configuration file
- min_wal_size                         80MB    configuration file
- password_encryption                  md5 configuration file
- pgaadauth.                           graph_api_endpoint  https://graph.microsoft.com configuration file
- pgaadauth.                           issuer_prefix   https://sts.windows.net/    configuration file
- pgaadauth.                           password_auth_enabled   on  configuration file
- random_page_cost                     2   configuration file
- search_path                          $user, public   configuration file
- shared_buffers                       1GB configuration file
- shared_preload_libraries             azure,pg_cron,pg_qs,pg_stat_statements,pgaadauth,pgms_stats,pgms_wait_sampling  configuration file
- synchronous_commit                   on  configuration file
- tcp_keepalives_count                 9   configuration file
- tcp_keepalives_idle                  120 configuration file
- tcp_keepalives_interval              30  configuration file
- TimeZone                             UTC configuration file
- wal_buffers                          16MB    configuration file
- wal_compression                      on  configuration file
- wal_keep_size                        400MB   configuration file

### Statistics: n_distinct, MCV, histogram

```
SELECT (SELECT sum(x) FROM unnest(most_common_freqs) x) frac_MCV, tablename, attname, inherited, null_frac, n_distinct, array_length(most_common_vals,1) n_mcv, array_length(histogram_bounds,1) n_hist, correlation
  FROM pg_stats
 WHERE attname='...' AND tablename='...'
 ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

gives:

- frac_mcv:
- tablename:   Skus
- attname:     Barcodes
- inherited:   FALSE
- null_frac:   0
- n_distinct:  -1
- n_mcv:
- n_hist:      101
- correlation: -0.060608394

Comment: The excerpt of pg_stats you provided is suitable for scalar attributes, but not for array attributes as you have here.  What are in most_common_elems and most_common_elem_freqs for the  Barcode attribute?

Comment: Can't check now, but: in extremely rare case I have 1 or 3 items within the array, for the rest (99% or more) the array contains 2 items. Every array item can appear in 2 records at most.

Answer (score 0):

It thinks there will be 25,637 qualifying rows and it will get to stop after reading only 11 of them, which would be quite fast if it were true.  But it actually has to read the entire table because there is only 1 qualifying row.

I think you are running into a problem [already known](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAMkU%3D1x2W1gpEP3AQsrSA30uxQk1Sau5VDOLL4LkhWLwrOY8Lw%40mail.gmail.com), that the pg_stats.most_common_elem_freqs is left null in this case, and then when the planner sees the NULL it assumes it will return 0.5% of the table which is way too high.  There was agreement it was a problem, but not a consensus on the best way to solve it, so no solution was ever implemented.  If you are willing to compile your own postgresql, you could try one of approaches discussed in the linked thread and see if those solve the problem for you.

The only practical solution I see is to install [pg_hint_plan](https://github.com/ossc-db/pg_hint_plan) and then provide a hint `/*+ BitmapScan("Skus") */` for the query.  But if you can't alter the query text, I don't see how you could inject the hint into it.  These hints are very much like Oracle's hints, so maybe your app has mechanism for doing that if it aims to be cross-platform.

Comment: The used of hints seemed promising, but I encountered a strange behaviour - to me - that I reported here: https://github.com/ossc-db/pg_hint_plan/issues/150

Comment: It is a case issue.  Your alias is not in double quotes in the query, so gets down-cased. So then it doesn't match the spelling given inside the hint (which does not get down-cased, whether it is in double quotes or not.)